# In fragment dont get the Latitude and longitude

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

i have a problem with my code, in a fragment i have this code:

```
public class Logo extends Fragment implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


LocationManager lm;
Location mLastLocation;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private Location mCurrentLocation;
private TextView Lat;
private TextView Long;
String provider;

public Logo() {

}
/**
 * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
 * number.
 */
public static Logo newInstance() {
    Logo fragment = new Logo();

    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    lm = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        Lat = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
    Long = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Longitude);
    TextView Morad = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Morada);
    Criteria c=new Criteria();
    provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);

    mLastLocation=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    Lat.setText("A obter");
    Long.setText(" dados");
    Morad.setText("Aguarde...");
    if(mLastLocation!=null)
    {
        Lat.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        Long.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
    else
    {
        Lat.setText("No connection");
        Long.setText(" wait");
    }
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        Lat.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        Long.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

But never get the Lat and Longitude values, what i missed up.
I only want to return the Latitude and Longitude values and put in the 2 filds.

Answer (score 0):

you need to decide if you are going to use the built in LocationManager or google play services Location APi because you are trying to use both and that will not work.

if you are trying to use the built in one then you never get a location because you dont have a last location and you never request location updates.

if you are trying to use the google play services location API well you need to do more work because you didnt really even implement it. I guess really in both cases you still have more work because you really didnt implement either correctly